# Add devices to a provisioning profile while Apple works on new developer center

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-id

Currently Apple is developing the new Developer Center, so I am not able to add new devices to my provisioning profile.

Is there another way to add a device to my apple-id and a provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are no other channels to allow you modify and regenerate provisioning profiles while the 'Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles' tools are down.  When working within the bounds of the non-jailbroken iOS security model, only Apple holds the private keys that make provisioning profiles pass their cryptographic checks during application installation and periodically during app execution.

In practice, this means you are in the exact same boat as the rest of us 3rd-party developers; When the Dev Center is taken offline, we are compelled to wait to make any account modifications until maintenance (or a rebuild as the case may be!) is complete.  Fortunately, the 'Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles' tool is now back online and you should be able to make the kinds of provisioning changes you asked about in your question.